# Use android 2.3 as a wireless Mass Storage middle man

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, storage, mount

**Context**:

I would like to use an old phone as a USB Mass storage `device/slave`, but read/writes to a Network share.  So I can attach it to the Kitchen TV and direct it to a `windows/linux` directory.

**Attempt so far**:

My test device is an unbranded tablet, which appears to try to clone a HTC Passion.  I'm able to access network shares from it, and make a mount point on the SD card of device.

However, when I activate the "USB Mass Storage", it totally unmounts every thing related to the internal/external storage, so it is accessible via the usb cable to the Host computer only.   ;(
When I remount the card and then remount the network share - it just makes it have a hissy-fit, and as you can guess its does not appear to read/write correctly.

Is there something available to do this?

**Alternatively**:

I’m kind-of familiar with USB programming from a Linux Host point of view, because I used to use `/proc/bus/usb/devices lsusb…` to know where to read/write the packets to.  But I don’t know how to do a program to act as a client/slave device.

I’m not aware of how to access the USB interface because I do not know where the io-file/memory address point could possibly be?

Reading `dmesg`, `/dev/bus/usb` or `/sys/bus/usb` does not appear to help me.

I’m defiantly missing something here, due to lack of knowledge.   :(
I know I’m asking to convert/overlay a block device on a network share, but I’ll worry about that later   :)

Comment: Definitely not doable. Network share = high level network protocol (CIFS/FTP/etc) vs. USB mass storage = block device (which is a level below and interpreted using a FAT32 driver on Windows). There's no way you can transform a high level protocol into a lower level one. Period. Silly comparison: You want to serve apples (raw device) but you only have apple juice (net share). You'd need iSCSI or so across the network.

Comment: Put it as answer! :-)

Comment: Found it "/sys/devices/platform/usb_mass_storage/lun#/file". Now just writing a basic block driver so its out of scope of this forum